# Dockerfile installing all python imports but when running the container the modules are not found

Tags: dockerfile, python-packaging, pythonpath

I am working for a company and I don't think I can exactly show the code but I have a basic docker file with

all the python packages are importes in this format

RUN pip install \

```
  netifaces \
  pytest \
```

etc...

and then to solve this problem i also tried using ENV PYTHONPATH "${PYTHONPATH}: " which directs itself to a path that I think should be where all the packages are installed. I don't think I used this right. the path i used directs itself to a venv file.

question. why inside my docker container I cant access python packages that i explicitly installed in the dockerfile. and what is the correct use of ENV PYTHONPATH. and is there a better fix so that i can make use of the python modules inside of my docker container.

mentioned above ^^^